# mysql insert fails for innodb

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i have a simple mysql table with innodb as engine and there are only three columns
and the server load is also very minimum always under 1 but i can see that there are only 4000 rows inserted but the the autoincrement number of id shows 21000 so i am not clear what does it mean. does it mean that there are 17000 insert failures
my table structure is

```
id           data1                remarks
1             this is text         1
2             another tedt         0
```

like that table grows but the autoincrement number is creating confusion for me.

i am using mysqli insert

```
 mysqli_query ($con,"INSERT INTO tablea (data1) VALUES ('$data1')");
```

please suggest/guide in clearing my doubt
at a time maximum 30/40 rows are getting inserted maximum

Comment: Have you checked how MySQL is configured regarding autoincrement?  It can be set up to increment by more than 1.  Also if an insert was part of a failed transaction, the row insert is rolled back but the autoincrement next value remains the same.

Comment: @GordonM i have seen but several times it increases with 1 interval but few times it increases with more than one as interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have solved the issue.if your column is unique and mysql tries to insert the data but the data could not be inserted as column is unique but the autoincrement number increases as it tried to insert the data but failed due to unique coulmn propoerties

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment number is never decremented, so 17000 means that there were 17000 inserts. If you have 4000 ties now, then it means that you probably also had 13000 deletes

Comment: there is no delete at all. several times it increases with 1 interval but few times it increases with more than one as interval